# In TCL 8.4, does the TclLib function Tcl_SetHashValue permit value to be NULL given #define NULL 0?

Tags: c, tcl, hashtable

I've read the documentation for Tcl_SetHashValue [1] but I have a question.  Does the TclLib function Tcl_SetHashValue permit value to be NULL given #define NULL 0?

In other words, given

```
#define NULL 0
```

does a Tcl_SetHashValue invocation like the following have a defined behavior?

```
Tcl_SetHashValue( someHashEntry, NULL );
```

If the behavior is defined, what is the behavior?  For example, if this code is executed

```
Tcl_HashTable myhash;
char *key_arg = 0;
Tcl_HashEntry *entry_arg;
ClientData val_arg;
Tcl_HashEntry *pEntry ;
char *pValue ;

Tcl_InitHashTable( &myhash, TCL_STRING_KEYS);

// store data

key_arg = "someKey";
entry_arg = Tcl_CreateHashEntry( &myhash, key_arg, &isEntryNew );
val_arg = NULL ;
Tcl_SetHashValue( entry_arg, val_arg );

// retrieve data

pEntry = Tcl_FindHashEntry( pArgs, criteria );
if (pEntry)
{
    pValue = Tcl_GetHashValue( pEntry ) ;
}
```

what would pEntry and pValue contain after the above code is executed?

1 - http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclLib/Hash.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value set by `Tcl_SetHashValue` (which is a macro, for historical reasons) is cast by the macro to be of type `ClientData`. That in turn is a typedef for `void *` (except on pre-C89 systems (!) where it is a `char *`) and has the **promise** that Tcl will not poke its grubby fingers inside it; a subsequent `Tcl_GetHashValue` will return exactly the value that you provided.

In your sample code, `pEntry` will have a pointer to a valid structure or a `NULL` if the criteria were not matched. If `pEntry` is non-`NULL`, `pValue` will have the value placed in. Which might well be `NULL` here; `NULL` is a perfectly fine thing to put in, and it's up to your code to understand what that might possibly mean.

---

Later versions of Tcl are the same, but might have tinkered with exactly what the definitions are. And for sure we dropped pre-C89 support. (In fact, it turned out we did so for building Tcl itself in 8.4 by accident and not one user complained. We're conservative, but not *that* conservative!)